# Should we use directus for developling complicated system?

Tags: social-networking, directus

I have an ideal to develop social network like open source Phpfox, SocialEngine (on Php). I want to develop API by using Node.js. Can I use directus to develop complicated system like that? Can directus allow me to write custom code for complicated logic. Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely! Directus doesn't do anything in particular with your data, it's completely yours and if you consider writing raw SQL queries then Directus will continue to work in the same way.